# Filtered HTML Text format without an editor

Tags: input-formats

How can I set up the following:

- Administrator should be able to use Full HTML with an editor window in Nodes.
- Users should be able to use Filtered HTML in Nodes without an editor - just the markup.
- Everybody should be able to use Filtered HTML in comments via markup - no editor.

Comment: Which editor are you trying to use?

Comment: Use ckEditor module.

Answer (score 1):

First you create your two text formats (if not already present).

Then you can use the wysiwyg module (http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) to display an editor for the Full HTML text format (on /admin/config/content/wysiwyg). wysiwyg will only display editors that you have set up properly (usually by placing a third party library in sites/all/libraries)

You can limit use of the text formats via the permission settings.